# How can i make a ajax call into aweber to getting a subscriber a list from codebehind in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, aweber

I want to get a subscriber email list from a web site so how can i get through ajax call from code behind?

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  WebRequest req =   WebRequest.Create("https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/1/lists/xxxxxx/");
  req.ContentType = "application/json";
  WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

Above "xxxxx" means a listname.but its give me a bad request error so how can i make a request from code behind in asp.net c#?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is the most likely cause of your problem. AWeber resources are addressed by numeric IDs, not by name. So for your "xxxxx", you would need the list ID rather than the list name as you indicated.

The list IDs together with the list names are visible right in the "lists" collection JSON when you retrieve:

```
https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/<ACCOUNT ID>/lists/
```

Another thing I noticed is that your URL has the account ID set to 1.  I suspect that's not an accurate account ID in your case.

To accomplish your goal of retrieving the email addresses, finally, you'll want to add "subscribers" to the end of your URL in order to hit the appropriate resource. While a "list" resource contains data specific to the list in question, the subscriber data is a whole additional level of detail.

Example URL:

`https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/<ACCOUNT ID>/lists/<LIST ID>/subscribers`

If you are still getting exceptions after making those changes, drop AWeber API Support (api@aweber.com) a note with the specifics.

Comment: if i want to get a subscribe list with appid then how can i do this?